# iPhone switch screen in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to iPhone app. I was told not to use Xcode storyboard for the app to be compatible with iOS4.3 and under.

Right now, I have 2 pages showing using a tabcontroller, however I am trying to add a page that loads up first when the program is started (i.e. a Login page), after authenticated the user will land on the first page of the 2 tabs.

What would I need to do? Should I create a MainWindow.xib file?

Thanks!

James

Comment: I think this questions will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989130/iphone-login-screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922527/uitabbarcontrol-with-a-login-screen Any doubt, just ask! Arildo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two solutions. You can :

*Create the window the the didFinishLaunching function in your AppDelegate, with something like that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    self.navigationController.delegate = controller;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

*or you can create the MainWindow.xib file with the AppDelegate and the window, and tell your app use this nib when launched. To do that :
In the .plist, enter MainWindow for the "Main nib file base name" characteristic.

Comment: Thanks!! I made the MainWindow file and assigned it as default like you said